# Which Normal Form will this relation will be in?

Tags: database, normalization

I am not clear in the concept of Normalization. The below problem has a loop in FD for the prime attributes pno->pname->pno so in which normal form will this be? Can we consider two **keys** while checking for NF?

Suppose we have WORKS_ON as following:`WORKS_ON(ESSN, PNo, PName*, Hours)`

FDs (suppose):

```
{ESSN, PNo} --> Hours
{ESSN, PName} --> Hours
PNO --> Pname
Pname --> PNo
```

Keys: `{ESSN, PNO}, and {ESSN, PName}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider *every* candidate key when you're evaluating FDs and determining normal forms.

For example, if a non-prime attribute is dependent on just part of *any* candidate key, the relation is not in 2NF. Think about it for a minute. It wouldn't make logical sense for the normal form to depend on *which* candidate key you chose, would it? Because then you could "change" the normal form just by evaluating against different candidate keys.

Comment: For FD A -> B that holds on relation R, either
A is its key, or 
B is a prime attribute. Then only it will be in 3NF. So here we have Pname / PNo as prime attribute? Wouldn't it be in 3NF?